# How to convert a JSON string array to XML correctly

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have a question about correctly representing a JSON string array in XML. I want to build the following JSON data (expected API input JSON):

```
{
  "relatiesoort": [
    "string"
  ],
  "modifiedOn": "string",
  "relatiecode": 0,
  "naam": "string",
  "vestigingsAdres": {
    "contactpersoon": "string",
    "straat": "string",
    "postcode": "string",
    "plaats": "string",
    "land": {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "uri": "string"
    }
  },
  "correspondentieAdres": {
    "contactpersoon": "string",
    "straat": "string",
    "postcode": "string",
    "plaats": "string",
    "land": {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "uri": "string"
    }
  },
  "telefoon": "string",
  "mobieleTelefoon": "string"
}
```

I initially want to build this in XML format and then convert it to JSON. I initially build the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
        <root>   
    <relatiesoort>string</relatiesoort>   
    <modifiedOn>string</modifiedOn>   
    <relatiecode>0</relatiecode>   
    <naam>string</naam>   
    <vestigingsAdres>
                <contactpersoon>string</contactpersoon>
                <straat>string</straat>
                <postcode>string</postcode>
                <plaats>string</plaats>
                <land>
                  <id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</id>
                  <uri>string</uri>
                </land>   
    </vestigingsAdres>   
    <correspondentieAdres>
                <contactpersoon>string</contactpersoon>
                <straat>string</straat>
                <postcode>string</postcode>
                <plaats>string</plaats>
                <land>
                  <id>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</id>
                  <uri>string</uri>
                </land>   
    </correspondentieAdres>   
    <telefoon>string</telefoon>   
    <mobieleTelefoon>string</mobieleTelefoon> 
    </root>
```

..... and then I use NewtonSoft.Json to translate it back to Json and feed it to the API.

But the problem is that if I convert it back to Json (this can also be done with this website: https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html) I get this result:

```
{
  "relatiesoort": "string",
  "modifiedOn": "string",
  "relatiecode": "0",
  "naam": "string",
  "vestigingsAdres": {
    "contactpersoon": "string",
    "straat": "string",
    "postcode": "string",
    "plaats": "string",
    "land": {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "uri": "string"
    }
  },
  "correspondentieAdres": {
    "contactpersoon": "string",
    "straat": "string",
    "postcode": "string",
    "plaats": "string",
    "land": {
      "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "uri": "string"
    }
  },
  "telefoon": "string",
  "mobieleTelefoon": "string"
}
```

As you can see the 'relatiesoort field' is not a JSON array anymore and the API gives an error as the JSON is not in the expected format.
What I want is to build the XML in a way that the relatiesoort field remains a Json array after converting it back to JSON.

To accomplish that: should I format this field as followed in XML?:

```
<relatiesoort>
    <element>klant</element>
</relatiesoort>
```

How can I accomplish this with the NewtonSoft.Json library?

Comment: If you know structure (so you can describe it as set of c# classes) of data then just deserialize from json and serialize to xml

Comment: Well the structure is not modelled with C# classes. I just want to build up the XML and convert it to JSON with the JSON string array format intact.

Comment: Convert json to json doesn't make any sense for me. Why just don't use an original json for API?

Comment: Well I build up the expected API input dynamically using functions that can build an XML document. I would need to change those functions and that is  a lot more work then simply building it in XML and then convert it to JSON (using NewtonSoft.Json).

Comment: But you are not just converting XML to json, you converting json to XML and then Xml to json, it doesn't make any sense for me

Comment: No I initially build the expected API data format in XML and then convert it to JSON.

Comment: " I initially build the following XML" Can you show the code you were using? "the relatiesoort field remains a Json array ", your xml doesn't show that it is an array, it is just a string property.

Comment: <relatiesoort> <element>klant</element> </relatiesoort> it will not work too, you need original classes with properties to mark it as array. Do you have the c# classes for XML? How do you bild an XML without class?

Comment: I use XElement(s) to build up the XML dynamically.

Comment: xElement.Add(new XElement("naam", "Serge"));

Comment: JSON and XML are not one to one replacement. There are different ways how to convert xml to json and vice versia. It depends on converter (mapper) settings. If I correctly understand Json.Net documentation (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm), `SerializeXmlNode` method interpret xml element as array if it has special attribute `json:Array='true'`. So, before serializing XmlNode to json string, you need to set this attribute for 'relatiesoort' nodes

Comment: This is the cleanest solution I think. Yes I will give this a try.

Comment: Does anybody know a code example of how to add json:Array='true' as an attribute to an XElement? The : character causes a lot of trouble.

Comment: @r-m85 https://code-maze.com/csharp-convert-json-to-xml-or-xml-to-json/

Comment: ^^Thank you. It works now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nothing points that relatiesoort is an array, You can't automatically convert string to array of strings, to convert automatically it shoud be

```
<relatiesoort>string</relatiesoort> 
<relatiesoort>string</relatiesoort>
```

in this case you need c# class with an array xml attributes of relatiesoort property. So the only way to make it correct, you need to convert XML To c# and serialize to a json string. If you don't have the class, another way is to parse your json and correct the value

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

if (jObj["relatiesoort"].Type != JTokenType.Array) 
{
jObj["relatiesoort"] = new JArray {jObj["relatiesoort"]};
json = jObj.ToString();
}
```

json

```
{
  "relatiesoort": [
    "string"
  ],
  "modifiedOn": "string",
   .....
}
```

Comment: This solved it. The API definitely 'eats' this Json (with the [). It is a bit of a work-around but it solves the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You should take a look at [this bit of doc](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/convertingjsonandxml.htm)

```cs
string json = @"...";
XmlDocument doc = (XmlDocument) JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Now from what I see, `vestigingsAdres` and `correspondentieAdres` look as if they are the same type of class object, but given how NewtonSoft works, most likely they will not be grouped under a collection. I can foresee that you may want this to potentially be a `Dictionary<string, yourObjHere>` so *if* that is the case, you will need to intervene by constructing the objects in memory and *then* serializing to JSON. To do this, you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourObj>(jsonString);` if you have already modeled the class object

If you are fine with just straight up dumping to XML as is, then don't worry

Comment: Sorry I have this reversed, will edit this give me a sec

Comment: Yes this is the way I do it now. I use: string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

Comment: Maybe I should use a certain formatting? I use Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None now.

Comment: So I'm indeed fine with straight up dumping to a JSON.

Comment: Formatting won't matter to the (de)serialization process at all, that's simply for human readability. I believe with omitting the formatting enum it defaults to none. If you wanted it to be human readable I believe its `Formatting.Indented`

Comment: But that being said to give it to the API you should leave it as `Formatting.None` as the API won't care for all the spacing

Comment: Ok yes that is clear. Thanks.